# Create a function to display hire date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I want to create a function with a parameter of a department name. Then I need to display which year has the most employees in that department. Any idea? Here's my code so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_date (v_name departments.department_name%type)
return employees.year(hire_date)%type is
v_date employees.year(hire_date)%type;
begin
SELECT e.year(hire_date) into v_date
FROM employees e
JOIN departments d
ON e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE d.department_name=v_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
return v_date;
end;
/

declare
my_var employees.year(hire_date)%type;
begin
my_var:=check_date('Shipping');
dbms_output.put_line(my_var);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function in Oracle DB, replace your function creating code as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_date(v_name departments.department_name%type)
  return INT IS
  v_date INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT EXTRACT(year from hire_date)
    INTO v_date
    FROM employees e
    JOIN departments d
      ON e.department_id = d.department_id
   WHERE d.department_name = v_name
   GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from hire_date)
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
  RETURN v_date;
END;
/
```

where

- the `EXTRACT()` function returns an integer type year value. So,
  convert `employees.year(hire_date)%type` to `INT` within the code in
  which you invoke the function, too.
- As using an aggregation function (`COUNT()` within `ORDER BY`
  Clause), a `GROUP BY` Clause is needed to be add to the query
- `hire_date` value is assumed to be non-null for each employee

Comment: Thank you. But when I tried this, it showed an error "not a single-group group function". Any idea? Thanks before! @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: well, you're right @sqlovers need to add GROUP BY clause as the satement having aggregation .

Answer (score 2):

just change GROUP BY condition in Barbaros's solution to

```
   GROUP BY extract(year from hire_date)
```

otherwise function will just return most recent year of hiring but not the most intensive one.

Comment: yeah, I missed, and included only the non-aggregated column, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `SQL` solution

In the first step you create a `VIEW` that contains for each department the *year* with the maximum number of `hire_dates`.

The important point is the handling of **ties**. The applied logic defines, if there are more years with the same maximal count the *highest* of such years will be considered.

This is *critical* as it makes the query *deterministic* - see the `order by` clause in the `row_number` analytic function.

```
create view deps_max_year as
with deps as (
 SELECT d.department_name, EXTRACT(year from hire_date) year, count(*) year_cnt
 FROM employees e
 JOIN departments d
   ON e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name, EXTRACT(year from hire_date)),
deps2 as (
SELECT department_name, year, year_cnt,
   row_number() over (partition by department_name order by year_cnt desc, year desc) as rn
from deps 
)
select *
from deps2
where rn = 1;
```

Now you can trivially query for the *max* year of some depertment with

```
select year
from deps_max_year
where department_name = 'Shipping';
```

If you *insist* you may of course integrate this query in a *function*. You may even integrate the view as CTO in the function.

The important point is you should not only   *order on the count* but also on the *year* to stay deterministic in case of *ties*.